# how do I set up a next and previous button

Tags: android

Hello as the title state I'm trying to setup a next and previous buttons but I'm still new at coding so this has me a little confused.

I tried to use if statements with an enum within a single button but it defaults to last if statement when the event is handled here's the code-

```
private enum EVENT{
    pe1, pe2, pe3, pe4;
}


 EVENT currentEvent = EVENT.pe1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_liners);

    nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    olText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.olText);






        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if (currentEvent==EVENT.pe1) {
                    olText.setText("PE1");
                    olText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(olText.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                    currentEvent=EVENT.pe2;
                }

                if (currentEvent==EVENT.pe2){
                    olText.setText("PE2");
                    olText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(olText.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                    currentEvent=EVENT.pe3;
                }
            }
        });


}
```

I tried to use the enumerator to assign a number to each if statement so when the user hit previous it would subtract and when they hit next it would add, each number would have some text or image within its if statement but as I said it defaults to the last if statement- Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have 2 buttons, a "NEXT" button and a "PREV" button? Then each has their on `onClickListener` so you know exactly which was clicked?

Comment: Sorry I didnt add the code for the prev button to the question but as you state both do exsist but I have the same problem with that button that I do with the next button so I only posted the next buttons code block. The problem is that it just defaults to the last code brick within that onclicklistener.

Comment: OK so describe what it is you want to happen when the NEXT button is clicked. Then what happens when the PREVIOUS button is clicked?

Comment: Alright the next button when clicked would show a new piece of text/img to the user and the previous button would just go back to the last text/img. At the end of the list it would revert to the first text/image shown if you hit next at the end or the last text/img if you hit previous at the beggining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
int eventNum = 0;
int maxEvents = XXX;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_liners);

    prevBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevBtn);
    nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    olText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.olText);

    setEventData(true);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v.equals(prevBtn) && eventNum > 0) {
                eventNum--;
                setEventData(false);
                return;
            }

            if(v.equals(nextBtn) && eventNum < maxEvents - 1) {
                eventNum++;
                setEventData(true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    prevBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

private void setEventData(boolean animLeft) {
    olText.setText("PE" + (eventNum + 1));

    if(animLeft) {
        olText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(olText.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
    } else {
        olText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(olText.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_right));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a class variable that keeps track of which text your TextView is showing. So in the following example, I create a list of Strings that I just store in a String array. Then I create an iterator variable which stores which String from the list I'm currently viewing in the TextView. Every time you click the previous or next button, you simply store your current state in the iterator variable so you can recall it the next time a click event comes in.

```
String[] labels = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
int currentView = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onPreviousButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickableLink);
    currentView--; //decrement our iterator
    if(currentView < 0) currentView = 0; //check to make sure we didn't go below zero
    textView.setText(labels[currentView]);
}

public void onNextButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickableLink);
    currentView++; //increment our iterator
    if(currentView > labels.length-1) currentView = labels.length-1; //check to make sure we didn't go outside the array
    textView.setText(labels[currentView]);
}
```